# How to use DecompressionStream with Response in Node?

Tags: node.js, promise, compression, cloudflare, response-headers

I am trying to decompress and serve a gzip file to the browser, using DecompressionStream and Response. Both methods work separately but not together.

Everything works until I return the Response. It seems like DecompressionStream set its own headers at some point, interfering with the returned Response.

I am unable to figure out where a promise is being made and how to handle it.

**I have the following code:**

```
const options = {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
        'content-encoding': 'gzip'
    }
}
const ds = new DecompressionStream('gzip');
const response = await fetch('files/test.gz'); //simple gzipped text file
const blob = await response.blob();
const decompressedStream = blob.stream().pipeThrough(ds);
return new Response(decompressedStream,options);
```

**Which gives the following error:**

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Cannot write headers after they are sent to the client`

What am I missing?

Please note that I am NOT using Express as a server. This is a simple Cloudflare Worker.

I have tried doing it in smaller steps and setting "await" everywhere but nothing helps.

I am new to using streams and piping, so I hope I'm doing something wrong there.

I can confirm that the decompression part works, as I did get it all to work with a very small test file, which I'm guessing got decompressed fast enough for the hidden promise to get resolved just in time.